# Embedded File gets corrupted after extraction from MS Word/PPT 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: ms-word, powerpoint

I have a tricky situation here.

When I extract a file embedded as an object in an MS Word (docx) / PPT (pptx) file (copy & paste the embedded file object on your desktop),
the extracted file is corrupted. (Some junk characters get appended at the start of the file and certain characters are missing from the end of the file).

I started facing the issue after I started using Windows 7!

Any known bugs in Office 2010 on Windows 7?

**Text File (Original)**
[image]

**Text File (After Copying & Pasting from a PPT (text file embedded as an object))**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey man I had the same problem and think I was able to solve it, at least in my case.  I had mostly zip files embedded in powerpoint, and what I found initially is that I could only extract them into a windows explorer directory by a copy-and-paste method, however this left the zip files corrupted in a strange way where the file structure was intact but the files could not be unzipped.  However I absolutely needed this data so I started to experiment with other ways to recover it.

Long story short, there is no means of extracting the file from powerpoint in the typical/intuitive ways that you would try first, without it getting corrupted.

What you have to do instead is literally double-click the icon in the powerpoint slide and let it open with the default app associated with that extension.  In my case, they were zip files, so once the zip program opened up I was able to extract the zipped files to wherever I wanted.

If your embedded file is in a weird format, or the default program for that type isn't helpful for re-saving it in another location, you might have to get creative with the filetype associations in windows to get it to open in something that will allow you to copy/save your file.  Fortunately in my case I didn't have to go that far, but I suspect it could be done if necessary.

Hope that helps.